# Simple CORS setup not working

Tags: node.js, express, superagent

Here is my server-code:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

// app.use(cors()); // Also tried this
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'OK' }));

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is my website code (served from `localhost:5000`):

```
const response = await superagent.get('localhost:3000/')
  .withCredentials()
  .send();
```

But this is blocked by CORS:

> Error: Request has been terminated
>   Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.

Why?

---

I am using Firefox 58 and Node.js 6.10.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `http://` prefix:

```
const response = await superagent.get('http://localhost:3000/')
  .send();
```

What a day...